# .htaccess rewriterule with backslashes in regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to 'catch' an URL with .htaccess rewriterule. How can I add backslashes to the rewriterule?

For example:

- http://www.example.com/page1 -> index.php?page=page1
- http://www.example.com/page1/subpage1 -> index.php?page=page1/subpage1

As you can see, I want the backslash between 'page1' and 'subpage1' IN the rewriterule, because the path can be variable (more subpages).

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But then I get an Internal Server Error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The internal server error is most likely due to reaching the redirect limit. `^(.*)$` matches “everything”, so it also matches `index.php?page=foo` again in the next round. So go research how you can exclude that from being rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

You get an Internal Server Error because your rule introduces an infinite redirect loop.

Here is what you want

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

It checks if the url is not a physical folder/file before rewriting it internally

Comment: It works! I didn't had the RewriteCond. Thank you very much!